# Verify that the branch has been tagged with the latest entry in the CHANGELOG

Tags: git, git-branch

I am writing a check in a Jenkins pipeline that verifies that the branch that has been checked-out had been tagged aswell.

In my repo I have a file `CHANGELOG.md` and its top entry is something like

```
## 1.0.1
 * Made this change
 * Made that change
```

Now the check basically gets the latest entry in the changelog and verifies if thats the entry used to tag the feature branch

So from the above file I can extract the tag value using

```
TAG=$(grep "##" file | head -1 | sed -e 's/## //g')
echo $TAG
1.0.1
```

Now I need to verify if the branch I am in has the same tag or not.

Doing a `git tag -l <tag>` does not seem viable solution to me since it will return ALL tags and not tell me whether the current branch is tagged or not. It also doesnt tell me of the tags are for the current branch.

`git ls-remote --tags` is only applicable for remote tags but again doesn't guarantee me whether the tag belongs to a particular branch or not.

What would be the best way to verify that the tag exists on a branch in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

To verify your current branch contains a tag you use can use `git branch --contains`

```
git branch --contains `git rev-parse TAGGY-X.Y.Z`
```